# Android emulator stays behind Android Studio after Run 'app'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0, macos-high-sierra

In Android Studio on `Run 'app'`, the emulator stays behind the Android Studio window, so to get it focused I have to hit Command+Tab.

Is there anyway that emulator window gets focused automatically once the app build/launch process is finished.

Its the default behaviour of Xcode, after the build process finishes, simulator window comes on top of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is. I have just gotten into the habit of immediately clicking on the emulator once I hit run. Could submit feedback and ask for this to become a feature though! I'll be doing that.